# Does XML allow use of namespace before declaration?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I found an example from a c# book as follows:

```
<text:directory                         
   xmlns:text = "urn:deitel:textInfo"   
   xmlns:image = "urn:deitel:imageInfo">

   <text:file filename = "book.xml">

      ...
```

It seems the namespace `text` is used to qualify directory **before** it is declared on the next line. Do I misunderstand something? The example code is correct, only I am unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML doesn't care about lines. They're just "white space". So the namespace isn't declared on the next line at all, it's declared within the same element where it is used.